# Google App Engine: Downloading Source: Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, download, war

I'm an owner on a project and I would like to pull down the war on GAE.  Through Cygwin, when I try to do this:

./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh download_app -A sampleapp -V

I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg

I suspect that this might be because I am behind a corporate firewall, but I have already configured my cygwin to reroute through a proxy.

Does anyone have other suggestions as to what might be the cause?

Comment: Smells like a classpath issue. Are you able to use appcfg.sh in Cygwin for other operations? Have you tried the non-Cygwin SDK build for Windows?

Comment: Actually it turns out that the issue was the corporate firewall.  Once I got to my home network, I was able to pull the war down without problems.

Comment: @noisebelt I doubt that was the cause of this.  This looks like a classpath error.  I don't think it looks over the wire for its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me.

```
sh appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes /ProjectPath/war
```

I could see in lot of document that the appcfg.cmd should be used but that didn't work but the above one looked good.