# Google Appengine: Unable to Vacuum Indexes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After reaching the 200 limit of indexes, i need to vacuum the indexes of my application.

Using AppEngine 1.8.6, if I launch the usual command for this operation

```
..\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6\bin\appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes C:\MyGaeProject\war
```

I get the following error

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) r
eturned error code 5.
Reading application configuration data...
ott 23, 2013 2:49:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:49:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:49:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/cron.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:49:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/queue.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:49:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
10% Found 79 local index definitions.

Error Details:
Line 0, column 12: Unable to find property 'application' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader$In
dexYaml

Unable to perform vacuum_indexes
Unable to perform vacuum_indexes
Please see the logs [C:\UserTemp\appcfg6705503051002284735.log] for further information.
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6\bin> .\appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes "C:\MyGaeProject\war"
ott 23, 2013 2:50:18 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Reading application configuration data...
ott 23, 2013 2:50:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:50:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
ott 23, 2013 2:50:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\MyGaeProject\war\WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
10% Found 0 local index definitions.

Error Details:
Line 0, column 12: Unable to find property 'application' on class:
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexYamlReader$IndexYaml

Unable to perform vacuum_indexes
Unable to perform vacuum_indexes
```

For testing purpose, I also tried and empty `datastore-indexes.xml`, but nothing

Even using Linux I get the same error

Same thing with Python

```
02:39 PM Application: my-gae-app
02:39 PM Host: appengine.google.com
02:39 PM Fetching index definitions diff.
Email: my-gae-email
Password for my-gae-email:
Error parsing yaml file:
Unexpected attribute 'application' for object of type IndexDefinitions.
  in "<string>", line 2, column 14:
    application: null
                 ^
```

As i can read, [i'm not the only one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/GPrigTyq8No/NX-V1kciFUcJ) experiencing this error

Already tried with older SDKs of Java, an new blank project and another GAE application, same problems so far

EDIT:
I updated Python SDK to latest version (1.8.6, was 1.8.5), the error above is not shown anymore, but now i'm getting another error

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the 1.8.6 SDK with Python? I haven't been able to reproduce the error there, but it is broken with 1.8.5.

Comment: You're right. Check the edited question above

Comment: Solved using python version and a new blank project

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest SDK [1.8.6] may resolve this.
I resolved the issue for Python SDK by installing the latest SDK.
The issue I met is:

```
Error parsing yaml file:
Unexpected attribute 'application' for object of type IndexDefinitions.
  in "<string>", line 2, column 14:
    application: null
                 ^
```

Comment: Upgrading to 1.8.8 also worked for me using the Java SDK and getting the same error described by @Kevin Zhu.

Answer (score 0):

For GAE/J, I use a command of the form (without the drive specifier):

```
appcfg.cmd --email=[E-mail address] vacuum_indexes "\MyGaeProject\war"
```

without problem (but I have not had to use this for some time). Obviously, you can omit the `--email` parameter, but you might want to try without the drive specifier (and quote the `war` folder just for fun).

Comment: Alreay tried this way, w/ or w/o email. Same error as described

Comment: here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463284/google-app-engine-downloading-source-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-goo/23109761#23109761

Answer (score 0):

You may have two options: 1. wait for the next sdk with bug fixes, or 2. open a ticket as specified here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10168